# C++ Build Error- expected class-name before '{' token|

Tags: c++, oop

I have the class below which inherits from a Collection class where I have virtual functions defined that I need to later on implement in my derived class below. I have yet to include the definitions for my member functions, except for the constructor of my derived class, in the .cpp file. However when I build my project, I get the following error message

**expected class-name before '{' token|**

I have tried everything I know to try, and am in need of assistance in understanding what I have wrong in my code and how I can go about fixing it.

```
    #ifndef VARIABLEARRAY_H
#define VARIABLEARRAY_H

#include "Collection.h"

using namespace std;

class VariableArray: public Collection{ 

        int* list[];// dynamic array that is resized on demand

    public:
        VariableArray();

};
#endif
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the `Collection` is a class not a template?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `Collection` symbol has already been seen by your translation unit?

You may want to add:

```
#include "Collection.h"
```

(or whatever the correct name is) before the class definition.

Comment: This seems more likely than my answer. My knowledge of C++ has failed me :p

Comment: It is seen . . . I only recently removed the #include "Collection.h" statement as I thought initially that this was some circular include problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also forward declare Collection:

```
class Collection;

class VariableArray : public Collection {
....
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you determine if `Collection` is available to the compiler?  Does the `class` declaration for `Collection` show up in the ***preprocessed*** output of your `VariableArray.cpp` file, or whatever the corresponding source file is?

Looking at the preprocessed output can help you determine:

- if namespace pollution is an issue (e.g. `#define` collides with `Collection`)
- if the `Collection` declaration is truly available before your `VariableArray` declaration.

If it's not a namespace pollution issue, I'd check if you are using the same `#include` guards in more than one header file.